# Regular expression groups not finding generic token

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to reduce a string down to the following tokens: singlequote, right paren, lparen, integer, whitespace and ID. ID being anything that isn't any of the others. My tokenizer isn't finding IDs.

```
import re
import collections

QUOTE = r'(?P<QUOTE>\')'
LPAREN  = r'(?P<LPAREN>\()'
RPAREN  = r'(?P<RPAREN>\))'
INT = r'(?P<INT>\d+)'
WS  = r'(?P<WS>\s+)'
ID = r'(<?P<ID>.*)'

tok_regex = '|'.join((QUOTE, LPAREN, RPAREN, INT, ID, WS))
Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['type', 'value'])

def tokenize(text):
    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, text):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group(kind)
        yield Token(kind, value)

tokenstream = tokenize(r'(123 a)')

print(next(tokenstream))
print(next(tokenstream))
print(next(tokenstream))
print(next(tokenstream))
print(next(tokenstream))
```

Give me this output:

```
Token(type='LPAREN', value='(')
Token(type='INT', value='123')
Token(type='WS', value=' ')
Token(type='RPAREN', value=')')
```

Why is the ID 'a' not being found? ID is before it in the regex. Is my ID regex not correct?

Comment: Is `(<?` just a typo in your ID-regex? - otherwise it's the reason for the fail

Comment: lol!! Thanks. So dumb!

Comment: Anyway, even after fixing this typo it won't work that way. Is the order fixed or not? If not, and there can be more token types, what does the ID consist of? If it consists of letters only, try using `(?P<ID>[^\W\d_]+)` (or ASCII only `(?P<ID>[a-zA-Z]+)`).

Comment: I figured that out myself in the interim. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ID = r'(?P<ID>[^\d\'\(\)\s]+)'
```

Fixed a typo, and grab everything that isn't one of the other tokens.